# Recreate admin user

Tags: 8, database

My login to Drupal 8 instance has failed. ive had a look in the DB and in the users table are 3 entries i dont recognise and the admin username (say 'adminuser') ive been using for the last year (but not accessed for several months) isnt there.

Ive contacted the hosting Co  - they can backup the whole DB to a time when 'adminuser' existed   but i could lose some data . Not too helpful about sorting out what has happened and when though.

Ive got cpanel access . can I recreate my adminuser through  phypmyadmin ? '

Comment: What D8 version is this exactly?

Comment: where can I find that in the DB ?

Comment: `drush uli -l www.example.com` will output you an one-time login link to access your site as admin.

Comment: Apart from that: your site probably got hacked.

Comment: does your server have Drush installed on it?

Comment: dont think so .

Comment: @leymannx, yes, I think so too, if this is Drupal <8.5.3. Then ask your hosting company to restore the site (database and code base) back to April 25th and update before going online again.

Answer (score -2):

Yes...

But know. The password field has been hashed.

Now their are a few ways to get the correct hashed value to manually add the updated/correct info. For example:

You can use a basic install on a localhost for example to create the user and export that table's content. On your live server via myphpadmin delete the user entery that has UID 1 and import the contents you exported. It will replace the username and password for you to be able to login.